# Connect to DocumentDB instance in public subnet for testing

Tags: amazon-web-services, mongo-shell, aws-documentdb, aws-cloud9

I have an AWS VPC with two public subnets. The route table has a public route `0.0.0.0/0` to the Internet gateway. Using CloudFormation I created a DocumentDB cluster with a single instance. I assigned it to both subnets, and I gave it a security group allowing ingress from `0.0.0.0/0` to port `27017`, but no egress at all (i.e. `0.0.0.0/32`). The instance is using the `default.docdb4.0` parameter group, which appears to already have `tls` set to `enabled`.

Now I want to connect to this DocumentDB instance with `mongosh` just to do a sanity test. I'd prefer to use secure connections. If I need to open up some more ports/routes temporarily, that's fine. But I'm not sure what I'm lacking.

### Attempt to Connect via SSH

Each DocumentDB instance has a "Connection & Security" tab showing how to connect manually.

1. I downloaded `rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem` as indicated.
2. I attempted to connect from my local machine, but using the latest `mongosh` rather than `mongo`:

```bash
mongosh --ssl --host ….docdb.amazonaws.com:27017 --sslCAFile rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem --username … --password …
```

I got:

> `MongoServerSelectionError: connect ETIMEDOUT x.x.x.x:27017`

The IP address given is one in the VPC, not a publicly routable IP address. Does DocumentDB not have a publicly routable address? (I'm pretty sure ECS Fargate services have publicly routable addresses.) What am I missing to be able to connect directly via `mongosh` to my DocumentDB in my public subnet?

*Update:* After more research, especially the similar question [problems connecting to AWS DocumentDB](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55578915), it seems that a DocumentDB instance in a VPC is simply not visible directly, as it has an internal IP address. (Even this is confusing, because [Working with a DB instance in a VPC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_VPC.WorkingWithRDSInstanceinaVPC.html) seems to imply that I can get a public IP address to the instance somehow, and as already mentioned I can with ECS Fargate. Maybe none of that applies to DocumentDB. But why can't I set up something like a load balancer I wonder that forwards from external to internal IPs?) The solution [seems to be SSH tunneling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/connect-from-outside-a-vpc.html), but even that has to be done from an EC2 instance or Cloud9 from within my VPC. So I guess unless I want to create an EC2 instance, my only remaining option is to figure out why Cloud9 won't start up.

### Attempt to Connect via Cloud9

At this point I thought that maybe I needed some EC2 instance within the VPC itself to connect to the DocumentDB instance. So for the first time I attempted to create a Cloud9 environment. I used the defaults, except that I selected the VPC in which the DocumentDB cluster+instance is running. Cloud9 took a long time to set up the environment. (While it was being created, I received an email from AWS saying, "You recently requested an AWS Service that required additional validation. Your request has now been validated …." I have no idea what that meant.) Finally Cloud9 gave a status of "Error" with a lifecycle status of "Creation failed":

> Cloud9 could not connect to the EC2 instance. Please check your VPC configuration and network settings to troubleshoot the issue.

I read [VPC settings for AWS Cloud9 Development Environments](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/latest/user-guide/vpc-settings.html), and it says that I need to have a route table with `0.0.0.0/0` to the Internet gateway (which I have). It also said I need a security group allowing SSH (port 22) connections. It wasn't clear *what* should have this security group, but I assume it means the Cloud9 EC2 instance (which I thought would be created automatically). Oddly I looked at the EC2 instance security group for the failed Cloud9 environment, and there were no inbound rules at all.

Admittedly there is a lot to read on the VPC settings page for Cloud9. I'll go back and try to wade through it all, but can anyone see right away what I'm missing just to spin up a Cloud9 environment to access my DocumentDB instance using `mongosh`?

### Update

Well at least I got it to create a Cloud9 environment. Using the console I had to select the "Secure Shell (SSH)" connection option. Every time I selected the "AWS Systems Manager (SSM)" connection option, it failed. I can't find any information on the difference between the two, or more to the point, why one would cause the *creation* of the Cloud9 environment to fail, even before I tried to connect to it.

Maybe someone can tell me what setting I need to add temporarily (preferably using CloudFormation) to access the DocumentDB instance from my local machine using `mongosh`?

Or is there some easier way to temporarily access my DocumentDB instance using `mongosh` for sanity testing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally was able to connect to my DocumentDB cluster in my VPC. Here are some things of note:

- There seems to be no way to connect directly to a DocumentDB cluster from outside the VPC. The DocumentDB cluster is not given a public IP address.
- Thus you can set up an EC2 instance or a Cloud9 instance in the VPC and connect from that—just make sure you select the correct VPC when creating the Cloud9 instance. For some reason I had to select the "Secure Shell (SSH)" connection option, as the "AWS Systems Manager (SSM)" would give me an error with a  lifecycle status of "Creation failed".

I went the Cloud9 route. You can use the Cloud9 terminal to install the MongoDB shell and then use it to connect to your DocumentDB cluster in the same VPC. See [Get Started with Amazon DocumentDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/get-started-guide.html) for an overview. Here are some tips from my experiences.

You can get the connection instructions from the console page for your DocumentDB cluster under "Connectivity & security". It assumes you've already installed the MongoDB shell, and assumes you're using the old version `mongo`. I preferred to use the newer `mongosh`, even though DocumentDB isn't compatible with the latest MongoDB versions, if nothing else than to ensure that the simple functionality I needed works with DocumentDB. So I followed the [official MongoDB installation instructions](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongodb-shell/install/), being sure to select "Amazon Linux".

Rather than typing some `echo` instructions, I typed `sudo nano /etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb-org-6.0.repo` and entered the following information to set up the latest (as of today) MongoDB Yum RPM repo:

```
[mongodb-org-6.0]
name=MongoDB Repository
baseurl=https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/amazon/2/mongodb-org/6.0/x86_64/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
gpgkey=https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-6.0.asc
```

Then installed `mongosh`:

```bash
sudo yum install -y mongodb-mongosh
```

Then finally I followed the connections instructions for my DocumentDB cluster from the console.

```bash
wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/rds-downloads/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem
mongosh --tls --host <cluster-info>.us-east-1.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017 --tlsCAFile rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem --username <username> --password <password>
```

Note that using the latest `mongosh` (v1.8.0), besides using `mongo` instead of `mongosh` it's best to also:

- use `--tls` instead of `--ssl`, and
- use `--tlsCAFile` instead of `--sslCAFile`.

Comment: Amazon DocumentDB is a VPC only service and it doesn't have a public endpoint. You could connect from other VPC, but you'll need to have VPC peering configured (or you could use Transit Gateway if you want to interconnect multiple VPCs more easily).